# Why after installing Vuetify some weird modifications implemented on divs and table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Laravel and VueJS for my training project. A few days ago I got familiar with Vuetify and that's something cool everybody would be willing to use. I did so. But After using the Vuetify project some weird modifications were implemented to my styles. For example, after using the vuetify this modified the main container and dropdown with a black border that is not defined by me anywhere. Also, it changed the design of my table changed colors, hover action, select dropdowns, inputs and much more of the same table. I then removed the vuetify code and my styles are again ok. But when I use vuetify it changes the styles of some divs, tables, hover actions, etc.

Here is the code i tried

## app.js

```
    import 'vuetify/styles'
    import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
    import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
    import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
    import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
    import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
    
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
      components,
      directives,
      icons: {
        defaultSet: 'mdi',
        aliases,
        sets: {
          mdi,
        },
      },
    })
```

## index.vue

```
    <v-btn color="#13af58" class="white--text">Submit Form</v-btn>
    <v-btn variant="plain" color="#3c88fe" size="small"> View  </v-btn> 
    <v-btn variant="plain" color="#3c88fe" size="small">Download</v-btn>
```

This is the only code I used from vuetify that is creating problems with the current styles (e.g. divs, tables, hover action, etc).

Here is the full code of `app.js` in case you want to check the full code

```
    // import './bootstrap';
    import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
    import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
    import '../css/app.css'
    import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress' 
    import {ZiggyVue} from 'ziggy'
    import MainHeader from '@/Pages/Components/MainLayout/MainHeader.vue'
    
    
    
    //Vuetify
    import 'vuetify/styles'
    import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
    import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
    import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
    import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
    import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
    
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
      components,
      directives,
      icons: {
        defaultSet: 'mdi',
        aliases,
        sets: {
          mdi,
        },
      },
    })
    
    
    
    // Icons Font-Awesome
    import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
    import {
      faPhone,
      faHouse,
      faNoteSticky,
      faMoneyCheckDollar,
      faReceipt,
      faEye,
      faBell,
      faCakeCandles,
      faPersonHalfDress,
      faArrowDown,
      faArrowUp,
      faGauge,
      faMoneyBills,
      faMinus,
      faGraduationCap,
      faHand,
      faHourglass,
      faUserSlash,
      faFileCircleCheck,
      faCircleCheck,
      faCircleXmark,
    } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    
    
    
    library.add([
      faPhone,
      faHouse,
      faNoteSticky,
      faMoneyCheckDollar,
      faReceipt,
      faEye,
      faBell,
      faCakeCandles,
      faPersonHalfDress,
      faArrowDown,
      faArrowUp,
      faGauge,
      faMoneyBills,
      faMinus,
      faGraduationCap,
      faHand,
      faHourglass,
      faUserSlash,
      faFileCircleCheck,
      faCircleCheck,
      faCircleXmark,
    ])
    
    InertiaProgress.init({
      delay: 0,
      color: '#29d',
      includeCSS: true,
      showSpinner: false,
    })
    
    createInertiaApp({
      resolve: async (name) => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')
        
        const page = await pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]()
        page.default.layout = page.default.layout || [MainHeader]
        return page
      },
      setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
          .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
          .use(plugin)
          .use(ZiggyVue)
          .use(vuetify)
          .mount(el)
      },
    })
```

Comment: vuetify components in simplistic terms are just wrappers around ordinary HTML elements with extra JS and CSS applied.  `import 'vuetify/styles'` imports vuetify's global CSS that is going to affect the look of your app, but that's what you tacitly agree to when using an opionated component library like vuetify.  now that you have `<v-select>` why would you choose to use normal `<select>`?  regardless, you always have the option to [customize the vuetify theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing) and/or override any CSS rules you're unhappy with.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. That okay but if i want to give style to some specific vuetify component for example i use v-btn i want to give some different styles when mouse hover over the v-btn. How do i get that result.

Comment: You can apply CSS overrides with CSS selectors that are with higher specificity than the CSS selectors used by Vuetify. Or, you can try [HeadlessUI](https://headlessui.com/) and style them with TailwindCSS or WindiCSS - you will have a complete control over the look.

Comment: @VUELOVER You can give a try to this Vuetify customization https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#manually-importing . It enables you to pick and choose which components to import.

Comment: HI, I tried importing the components i need. I just imported the V-btn thats fine but the catch is that styling is not genuine that is required.